# How do I run a function onload and then call it again from an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    var $rows_views = $('.view-display-id-block_1 .view-content').find('[class*="views-row-"]'); 
    $rows_views.each(function(index) { 
        $('.show-more').click(function() {
            if (index > (($rows_views.length / 3) - 1)) { 
                $('.views-row-' + (index + 1)).toggle(); 
            } 

            $('.pager').toggle(); 
        });
    });
});
```

I want to run it to hide the rows and then toggle it whenever the button gets clicked to show them. How do I run a function at document ready and then run again that function in a click event?

Comment: You put your code in a function, call that function from $(document).ready, and specify the same function in your click event

Comment: you can wrap it in to a function and reuse that function with onClick

Comment: + also look in to using DOM traversal instead of incremental class/id attributes. It makes your code simpler and more DRY

Comment: is it possible to update the question with the function that you want to refactor?

Answer (score 2):

As someone else states in the comments above, you can move the function you call in your click event outside and to the top of your document ready function, and then simply call it again (by name) in the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    // Invoke your function here
    callMeTwice();


    // define your function here
    function callMeTwice () {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    // Invoke your function again within the click event here
    $(domElement).click(callMeTwice);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your `function` outside the `(document).ready()` scope and you should be able to call from your `element` and from your ready `function`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  myFunc(); // You call your function here
  
  });

function myFunc() {
  alert('click'); // You do your action here aka hide show
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p onclick="myFunc();">click me </p><!--note the onclick attribute-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a .click() function and put your $rows_vies_each thing in a function.

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";

var clickMe = document.getElementById('idOfThingToClick')

var $rows_views = $('.view-display-id-block_1 .view-content').find('[class*="views-row-"]'); 

function bestFunction(){
  $rows_views.each(function(index) { 
      $('.show-more').click(function() {
          if (index > (($rows_views.length / 3) - 1)) { 
              $('.views-row-' + (index + 1)).toggle(); 
          } 

          $('.pager').toggle(); 
      });
  });
}
$(clickMe).click(function(){
  bestFunction();
})
});
```